# MobileFirst 8.0 user authentication LDAP error

Tags: java, ldap, ibm-mobilefirst

I'm currently with a migration from IBM Worklight 7.0 to IBM MobileFirst 8.0. At the present moment, I'm facing the user authentication functionality which is checked against an LDAP server, and I'm a total newbie about LDAP...

I was trying to connect to a free LDAP server that I've check is available for testing purposes (described [here](https://www.forumsys.com/tutorials/integration-how-to/ldap/online-ldap-test-server/)). This is my code so far (extracted from this [LDAP connector snippet](https://github.com/mfpdev/ldap-sample/blob/master/readme.md) from IBM team):

```
        if (credentials != null && credentials.containsKey(USERNAME) && credentials.containsKey(PASSWORD)) {
            String username = "gauss";
            String password = "password";

            Hashtable<String, String> env = new Hashtable<String, String>();
            env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
            env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");
            env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "ldap://ldap.forumsys.com:389");

            SearchControls sc = new SearchControls();
            String[] attributeFilter = { "uid", "cn" };

            sc.setReturningAttributes(attributeFilter);
            sc.setSearchScope(SearchControls.SUBTREE_SCOPE);

            try {
                LdapContext ldapContext = new InitialLdapContext(env, null);
                String searchString = "(&(uid=%v))";
                searchString = searchString.replaceAll("%v", username);

                // Search the user
                NamingEnumeration<SearchResult> searchResults = ldapContext.search("", searchString, sc);
                ArrayList<SearchResult> searchResultsList = Collections.list(searchResults);

                if (searchResultsList.size() != 1) {
                    errorMsg = "Wrong Credentials";
                    return false;
                } else {
                    // login with user DN + password
                    SearchResult searchResult = searchResultsList.get(0);

                    ldapContext.addToEnvironment(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, searchResult.getName());
                    ldapContext.addToEnvironment(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, password);
                    try {
                        ldapContext.reconnect(null);
                        userId = (String) searchResult.getAttributes().get(config.getLdapUserAttribute()).get();
                        displayName = (String) searchResult.getAttributes().get(config.getLdapNameAttribute())
                                .get();
                        return true;
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        logger.info(e.toString());
                        errorMsg = "Wrong Credentials";
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                errorMsg = "Connection to user repository failed";
                logger.info(e.toString());
            }
        } else {
            errorMsg = "Credentials not set properly";
        }
```

Execution fails on *ldapContext.search("", searchString, sc)* and I'm not sure about the reason:

```
 javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: [LDAP: error code 32 - No Such
 Object]; remaining name ''
```

So far, execution seems to be pretty simple... Anybody can help me with this error?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should start with the search filter. Different LDAPs might have different ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After few iterations of *test-error* I discovered how to execute the search:

`ldapContext.search("dc=example,dc=com", searchString, sc)`